# putting a Django website on production using sqlite data base

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, host

hey I'm currently working on a website (Photo selling services) and now I wanna deploy it on a public host,
I didn't change the database and I'm using Django's SQLite as my database, Is it gonna be a problem or it's fine?
and also I'm handling the downloads with my views and template and the files (photos) will be downloaded from my database and I wanted to know do I need one host for my application and another for putting my photos in? or I can just run the whole website on one host without a problem ( same as I'm running it on my local host).

Comment: For a low-traffic site, it will probably be absolutely fine.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer not to use SQLite in production because:

1. **It is just a single file and it may get deleted suddenly by anyone that has access to that**.
2. **No user management**.
3. **Limited data types**.

For serving files on a heavy-traffic website it's good to have CDN to serve files from.